# MongoDb NoRM Linq issue

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm, nosql

I'm trying MongoDB with NoRM in C# and can't figure out why my LINQ queries don't work. Something as simple as this:

How can this return all documents with all the fields/properties 
populated:

```
    return Collection.FindAll().Documents.ToList();
```

but this one only returns the correct number of documents with only 
the ID field populated? The rest of the object are empty/nulls?

```
    return Collection.Linq().ToList();
```

Here is how collection is defined:

```
    public IMongoCollection<T> Collection 
    { 
        get { return _database.GetCollection<T>(); } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does the Linq method come from?  If you want to return all items in the collection into a List, one of the two following options should work...

```
return Collection.AsQueryable().ToList();

return Collection.Find().ToList();
```